# Default sort my own order without sort by

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select id from MyTable where id in (28,5,7,35)
```

I want to leave the order as is in the in Clause, however SQL output is ordered by ID

I know how to achieve the result using a temp table. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Learn this lesson well - rows in a resultset and in a table have no inherent order. Any order you "see" is an artifact of the execution plan if the query that generates those rows does not include an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Where does this list of IDs come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by *I know how to achieve the result using a temp table* as you haven't shown this, however you could insert your values into a temp table / table variable with an Identity in the order you require the results, then inner join. This is likely the most performant option for larger result sets.

Note that if you want a result set in a specific order, you *must* specify an *order by* clause.

```
declare @filter table(seq int identity(1,1), id int)
insert into @filter values (28),(7),(5),(35)

select * 
from TheTable t
join @filter f on f.id = t.id
order by f.seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression in the `order by` clause:

```
select id
from MyTable
where id in (28,5,7,35)
order by case id
when 28 then 1
when 5 then 2
when 7 then 3
when 35 then 4
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. It is a great solution for small data. If you have many rows it will be difficult to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using a bit of JSON

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(50) = '28,5,7,35'

Select A.*
 From  YourTable A
 Join  OpenJSON( '['+string_escape(@S,'json')+']' ) B on A.ID=B.Value
 Order by B.[Key]
```

If it helps with the visualization, the JSON portion returns the following...  `key` becomes your actual sequence.

```
key value   type
0   28      2
1   5       2
2   7       2
3   35      2
```

Note:  the string_escape() is just a precaution and may not be necessary provided you supply a delimited string of integers.

If you have alphanumerics, this would format the JSON array.

```
Declare @S varchar(50) = 'Act28,5,Usr7,ZZZ35'
Select * from OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(@S,'json'),',','","')+'"]' )
```